# Не могу понять суть Полиморфизма в классах

Tags: c#, полиморфизм

У нас есть допустим базовый класс и класс который наследуется от базового класса.
Зачем нам наследника превращать в базовый класс и отбрасывать всю его индивидульность, чтоб остались только базовые свойства.
Базовый класс допустим Person p
Дочерний (наследник) Doctor d

p = d; //мы сейчас дочерний класс превратили в базовый, отбросили его свойства.
d = (Doctor)p //сейчас вернули ему обратно его индивидуальные свойства.
Непонятно зачем такое делать.

Comment: это называется downcast, тут полно ответов на такие вопросы - гляньте [поиск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=downcast)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы определил полиморфизм в ООП как способность класса иметь собственную реализацию функциональности, определённой (декларированной) в базовом классе.

Приведу отрывок из книги Д. Албахари "C# 9.0. Справочник. Полное описание языка".

---

**Полиморфизм**

Ссылки полиморфны, т.е. переменная типа `х` может ссылаться на объект подкласса `х`. Например, рассмотрим следующий метод:

```
public static void Display (Asset asset) {
  System.Console.WriteLine(asset.Name);
}
```

Метод `Display` способен отображать значение свойства `Name` объектов `Stock` и `House`, т.к. они оба являются `Asset`:

```
Stock msft
House mansion = new House ... ;
Display (msft);
Display (mansion);
```

В основе работы полиморфизма лежит тот факт, что подклассы (`Stock` и `House`) обладают всеми характеристиками своего базового класса (`Asset`). Однако обратное утверждение не будет верным. Если метод `Display` переписать так, чтобы он принимал `House`, то передавать ему `Asset` нельзя:

```
Display (new Asset()); // Ошибка на этапе компиляции
public static void Display (House house) { // Asset приниматься не будет
  System.Console.WriteLine(house.Mortgage);
}
```

---

**Далее уже от себя.**

Вот очень показательный пример полиморфизма. Объект класса `B` можно присвоить переменной `a` типа `A`, потому что он, наследуя `A`, обладает всеми его свойствами. Но в тоже время он остаётся объектом класса `B`, и применив к `a`, которая объявлена типом `A` (который ничего не знает про `B`), метод `Con`, мы получаем этому подтверждение на консоли.

```
using System;
static class Programm {
    class A {
        public virtual void Con() {
            Console.WriteLine("A");
        }
    }
    class B : A {
        public override void Con() {
            Console.WriteLine("B");
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        A a = new B();
        a.Con(); // B
    }
}
```

То есть полиморфизм позволяет работать со всеми разнообразными наследниками базового класса единым образом, определённым в базовом классе, сохраняя, в тоже время, индивидуальность каждого объекта.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
static class Programm {
    class A {
        public virtual void Con() {
            Console.WriteLine("A");
        }
    }
    class B : A {
        public override void Con() {
            Console.WriteLine("B");
        }
    }
    class C : A {
        public override void Con() {
            Console.WriteLine("C");
        }
    }
    class D : A {
        public override void Con() {
            Console.WriteLine("D");
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        List<A> alist = new List<A> { new B(), new C(), new B()
            , new D(), new D(), new C() };
        foreach (var a in alist) a.Con(); // B C B D D C
    }
}
```

Кстати, другой тип полиморфизма в программировании - это генерализация, или использование шаблонов типов `<T>`. Но это не имеет отношения к ООП.

Comment: А можно ли сказать так:? Что базовый метод используется в каждом наследнике по разному? Мне бы для начала очень простое определение, на подобии того что я сказал. Просто мне кажется что я понимаю что это такое, но не могу сформулировать. Мы создаём базовый класс, задаём ему определённые свойства, и создаём и наследуем от базового класса, и у каждого наследуемого класса, будет своя реализация, свойства, параметры, размеры и тд, но общая концепция идёт от базового класса, как шаблон, по которому мы лепим что то и модернизируем под свои нужны. Я в правильном ручье думаю?

Comment: "базовый метод используется в каждом наследнике по разному" - не используется, а реализуется. В целом верные рассуждения. Я добавил в ответ простое определение полиморфизма.